# how to increase value of a variable integer in python

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, overriding

```
import re
score = 0

capital_letters = r'[A-Z]'
a = re.compile(capital_letters)

lowercase_letters = r'[a-z]'
b = re.compile(lowercase_letters)

def increase_score (aValue, aScore):
  aScore += aValue
   return aScore

def upper_score(test_string, aScore):
  if re.match(a, test_string):
    aScore = increase_score(5, aScore)
    print (aScore)
    print("UPPERCASE")
  else:
     print("The password needs capital letters for a higher score")


def lower_score(test_string, aScore):
    if re.match(b, test_string):
      aScore = increase_score(5, aScore)
  print (aScore)
  print("LOWERCASE")
else:
  print("The password needs lowercase letters for a higher score")

password = input("Enter a password to check")
upper_score(password, score)
lower_score(password, score)
```

If I input all upper case letters I get this output:

```
5
UPPERCASE
```

The password needs lowercase letters for a higher score
If I input all lower case letters I get this output:

```
The password needs capital letters for a higher score 
5 
LOWERCASE
```

When i mix upper case annd lowercase i get this output:

```
 5
 UPPERCASE
 5
 LOWERCASE
```

Even though there are both uppercase and lowercase letters the score is still 5 instead of 10.

I want the score to be cumulative and build ontop of each other.

Comment: You changed only the local copy of the score; you never changed `score` in your main program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send the score to the function:

```
upper_score(password, score)
```

you are actually sending a copy of the score. In your example it recieves `score` which has a value of 0, and creates a new variable `aScore` with also a value of 0, so when you change `aScore` you don't actually change `score`.
(Be careful, even if they had the same name they still wouldn't be the same variables.)

There are a few ways to do what you are trying to do. 
The simpler way would be to simply make the function return `aScore` and there you can add it to your `score`.

```
def upper_score(test_string, aScore):
  if re.match(a, test_string):
    aScore = increase_score(5, aScore)
    print (aScore)
    print("UPPERCASE")
  else:
     print("The password needs capital letters for a higher score")
  return aScore


def lower_score(test_string, aScore):
    if re.match(b, test_string):
      aScore = increase_score(5, aScore)
      print (aScore)
      print("LOWERCASE")
    else:
      print("The password needs lowercase letters for a higher score")
    return aScore

password = input("Enter a password to check")
score += upper_score(password, score)
score += lower_score(password, score)
print("total score: " + score)
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Did you forget the `return aScore` at the end of the 2 function?